# Check if List is not empty with Pydantic in an elegant way

Tags: python, pydantic

Let's say I have some `BaseModel`, and I want to check that it's `options` list is not empty. I can perfectly do it with a `validator`:

```
class Trait(BaseModel):
    name: str
    options: List[str]

    @validator("options")
    def options_non_empty(cls, v):
        assert len(v) > 0
        return v
```

Are there any other, more elegant, way to do this?

Comment: I wasn't that clear: I'm not looking to shrink the size of validator function, I'm looking to find a way not to use it at all.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you want to use a `@validator`:

```py
return v if v else doSomething
```

Python assumes *boolean-ess* of an empty list as False

If you don't want to use a `@validator`:

In Pydantic, use [`conlist`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/types/#pydantic.types.conlist):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, conlist
from typing import List

class Trait(BaseModel):
    name: str
    options: conlist(str, min_length=1)
```

Comment: Is `return v if v` syntactically correct? What am I missing?

Comment: it's not, it was meant to imply `else someOtherExpression`. OP I believe, was interested in my `conlist` answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, empty lists are falsey, while lists with any number of elements are truthy:

```
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool([1,2,3])
True
>>> bool([False])
True
>>> bool([[]])
True
```

This means that you can simply `assert v` or `assert Trait.options` to confirm that the list is non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use [`Field`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/fields/) with [`min_length`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/fields/#string-constraints):

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class Trait(BaseModel):
    name: str
    options: List[str] = Field(min_length=1)
```

*`min_length` is on the string constraints session but still works for lists.*

Answer (score 0):

As of Python 3.9 and Pydantic v2, the recommended way is to use `Annotated` types:

```py
# tested with Python 3.9 & Pydantic 2.6

from typing import Annotated
from annotated_types import Len
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Foo(BaseModel):
  my_list: Annotated[list[str], Len(min_length=1)]


ok = Foo(my_list=["bar"])

# this will throw a ValidationError exception
too_few = Foo(my_list=[])
```

References:

- [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.6/concepts/types/#composing-types-via-annotated)
- [annotated_types: MinLen, MaxLen, Len](https://github.com/annotated-types/annotated-types?tab=readme-ov-file#minlen-maxlen-len)