# Type hint expected boolean and always empty list

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, duck-typing

I have a list that I only need to check if it's empty or not.

```py
check = [] and True
print(check) # prints []
```

```py
check = [1] and True
print(check) # prints True
```

I only want to use `check` in an `if` statement to check the truthiness of the variable, like so:

```py
if check:
    print('Passed')
```

Should I type hint it like this?

```py
from typing import Literal, Union
check: Union[Literal[True], Literal[[]]] = [] and True
```

I don't even know if this how to annotate an always empty list, but the annotation itself seems silly, because to the reader, it only matters about the truthiness of it. Ideally I would just want `check: bool =  [] and True`, but the statement doesn't always return a `bool` so it seems incorrect.

There is also this option to turn it into a `bool`:

```py
check: bool = not not [] and True
```

or

```py
check: bool =  bool([]) and True
```

but these seem like extra work for no reason, since I just need the truthiness and that is acquired regardless of whether I get an empty list or `False`.

So, what is the proper way to annotate that a statement is to be interpreted only in a boolean context, if itself does not return a bool? Do I just convert it to be boolean and annotate with `bool`, or do I use something like `Union[Literal[True], Literal[[]]]`? And a side note, I don't know if `Literal[[]]` is even the proper way to annotate an always empty list (or if it's possible at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This almost feels like an inherently bad candidate for type-checking, to me. In this specific situation, you don't actually care about the type of the value returned, so long as you can call `bool` on it to test for its truthiness. Unless you're working with `pandas`/`numpy` or similar, there are very few python objects you can't call `bool` on — it doesn't require the presence of the `__bool__` method or anything — so you can't use the usual solution for duck-typing, which would be to use `typing.Protocol`. (See, for example, the `SupportsInt` and `SupportsRound` classes in the `typing` module, both of which test for the presence of certain methods.)

As a result, I'd argue a hint of `typing.Any` would be just as informative and correct as a more elaborate one like `typing.Union[list, bool]`. The extra information in the second one is entirely redundant for your purposes, it would seem to me.

Comment: I feel the same way. I like to accurately hint but I don't want to make the code itself more complex just to match a type hint either. It's definitely a weird one

Comment: Precisely. It's annoying — I tried to write a `SupportsBool` protocol, but python lists have no `__bool__` method so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way to annotate it is to use `Union[List, bool]` but Type Hints would'nt do data validation to check if the list is empty - for that take a look at PyDantic explored in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61468548/check-if-list-is-not-empty-with-pydantic-in-an-elegant-way)

```
from typing import List, Union


def check_list(my_list: Union[List, bool]):
    if my_list:
        print("got truth")
    else:
        print("got false")
```

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of PyDantic before. I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1):

Core Python allows for dynamic typing. If you know that you only want to use `check` in a boolean context annotate it with bool and use `and True`.

```
check: bool
check = [] and True    # will contain []
...
check = [1] and True   # will contain True
```

This gives no warnings when I test it in PyCharm.

You can also use:

```
check: bool = [] and True    # will contain []
...
check: bool = [1] and True   # will contain True
```

which gives no warning either...

Comment: For a little more context, `and True` is actually just another truth check in my code, but I used that for simplicity here. But yeah, seems fine and simple enough, thanks!

Comment: As is often the case, it looks like pycharm is okay with this while mypy stubbornly complains :/ https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=dd1dc1e32ef169c01ba9b4adc93f7c16